# Meaning of "What to you are going to take?"

Tags: meaning

The sentence is as follows:

> So let’s say you’ve made your own mind up about this method and what to you are going to take?

What would you mean when you say

> What to you are going to take?

Comment: It means nothing; it's nonsense. "...what *route* you are going to take" would work.

Comment: That isn't a grammatically correct sentence.

Comment: Yep, gibberish.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks the meaning of an invalid text

Comment: Original text https://books.google.it/books?id=79U2CgAAQBAJ&pg=PT30&lpg=PT30&dq=So+let%E2%80%99s+say+you%E2%80%99ve+made+your+own+mind+up+about+this+method+and+what+to+you+are+going+to+take&source=bl&ots=wdgHwVQqys&sig=lJwBHwCl7DRmdq_A8lJBvABYnbg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRgqaqx6rNAhXEFSwKHZ-VDzgQ6AEIKjAC#v=onepage&q=So%20let%E2%80%99s%20say%20you%E2%80%99ve%20made%20your%20own%20mind%20up%20about%20this%20method%20and%20what%20to%20you%20are%20going%20to%20take&f=false the author made a mistake.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. For me as a non-native it's hard to tell whether the sentence is informal or simply nonsense. But you proved my assumption.

Answer (score 2):

This is a grammatically incorrect sentence - likely a misspelling (eg. "to" for "tool") or simply erroneous because the author was not thinking at the time.